# How to get this information using LINQ

Tags: linq

I have a database which I access using entity framework. Here's a snippet.

[image]

As you can see a Tier can have multiple MatchNodes and each MatchNode can have multiple LenderMatchNode.

I have an integer variable **fundedCount**.

What I'm trying to do is filter a list of Tier/MatchNode/LenderMatchNode where fundedCount is between LenderMatchNode.MinFunded and LenderMatchNodeMaxFunded.

Essentially this should return a list of Tier which in turn should have a list of MatchNode which should have 1 LenderMatchNode.

Anyone help?

Comment: Linq-to-what is this? If you want it exactly as stated you want objects with partly loaded collections. The ways to get there are pretty different with linq-to-sql or entity framework. Or are you OK with anonymous types containing the info you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Tiers.MatchNodes
                  .LenderMatchNodes
                  .FirstOrDefault( lmn => lmn.MinFunded <= fundedCount && lmnMaxFunded >= fundedCount )
                  .Where(rs => rs != null);
```

The result will be a hard list of LenderMatches which fall into the where criteria. From their you can group out what is needed such as the MatchNodes or tiers.

Comment: Just tried it out - MatchNodes is available from Tiers, however LenderMatchNodes is list within a list and will need something like a SelectMany()

Comment: @dotnetnoob a SelectMany in that situation will distill down the results as needed yes.

Comment: I'm sorry, not very proficient with linq so don't really understand your previous comment

Comment: @dotnetnoob SelectMany is use full in taking a many to many (list of list<t>) and just making list<t>. I was just stating yes, you may need to use SelectMany.